# Sample Lifespan IHP USB key file please

Tags: treadmill, tracking

I bought a Lifespan folding treadmill (TR1200i, but similar models will possibly use the same format) in a private sale and it seems it requires some online account with "IHP" to just update the name/age/weight/height that *my* treadmill displays and uses to calculate calories.

Can someone with a USB stick and some technical knowledge share a sample of what gets put on the stick?  Is it just one file?  Is it text or binary?  Is it encrypted?  I just want to make mine without their help.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question on specific hardware

Comment: If you have the treadmill and feel like sharing, please do so.  If you don't then move on to the next question.

Comment: I read it as a "gear and gadgets used during exercise" question, so it seems fine to me. http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/239/questions-about-fitness-equipment

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about fitness.

Comment: @Noumenon - The gear and gadgets are about how to use them IN a specific workout/program, not how to program them.

Comment: The ability to set the weight and height in the computer is as important for correctly monitoring calorie burn or heart rate as securing the physical safety pin in other pieces of equipment.

Comment: just use "Note pad" save as txt file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a tech support question, unrelated to actual exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my TR4000i, it's a plain text file IHPUSER.TXT:

```
name,jason,
age,45,
sex,male,
weight,167,
height,70,
```

*I don't know how to accomplish this in this editor, but the file ends below the "height,70," line rather than at the end of it.*

There may be more to this file/format that I just I haven't entered on the LifeSpan web site.

And further detail on the Chris H answer about the log file:

- Columns 5 and 6 in USER.txt are calories and steps, respectively.
- Speed and distance for me are measured in MPH and miles.
- The treadmill writes to the log every twenty seconds; on mine the light changes from green to red momentarily during the write.
- The first entry of a subsequent run is entered immediately below the last entry of the previous run.
- When I upload to the LifeSpan web site the USER.txt file is deleted and the IHPUSER.TXT file is rewritten.

I'm not getting enough value from my LifeSpan account to make it worth continuing--I expect I'll let it lapse and just do my own analysis of the log with Excel.

Comment: AWESOME.  Can't wait to try it thanks.  If you have anything to add about "User 2" (from my memory, it supports two users) that'd be great too.

Comment: Ah!  I guess it's one user per file/usb stick.  But it works!  Easy!  Thanks!

Comment: Further, there doesn't seem to be a way to change the defaults for when no usb key is plugged in.  It shows 30yrs, 167lbs when nothing is plugged in which are perhaps fixed averages.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran on a 1200i and a USER.TXT file showed up in the root of my USB with the following data. Here is my guess for the fields: Date,Time,?,??,??,Speed,Distance,??,??,??

```
11/04/2015,06:18:01,T,000,0000,0000,00.5,00.00,0000,,E,
11/04/2015,06:18:22,T,000,0000,0000,00.5,00.00,0000,,E,
11/04/2015,06:19:08,T,000,0000,0015,03.0,00.01,0000,,E,
11/04/2015,06:19:28,T,000,0001,0052,03.0,00.02,0000,,E,
11/04/2015,06:19:48,T,000,0005,0095,05.0,00.04,0000,,E,
11/04/2015,06:20:08,T,000,0008,0150,06.0,00.08,0000,,E,
11/04/2015,06:20:28,T,000,0011,0204,06.2,00.11,0000,,E,
11/04/2015,06:20:43,T,000,0015,0243,07.0,00.14,0000,P,E,
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there any way to set up the User 1 and User 2 ages, weights, etc from your lifespan website account (assuming you have one)?  Are you supposed to put a downloaded settings file on the USB stick which might get picked up by the treadmill next time it is plugged in?  I didn't think ahead that it would log your run which is neat, but I'm looking for the settings-type file.

Comment: (You might scramble up any numbers that look like they might identify you or your account)